# SQL Server - SUM Preceding Rows With Condition Linked to Original Row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

For each row in the below example data set, the code does a sum of the previous 5 rows when a certain condition is met.

The problem I'm having is the condition needs to reference the original row rating e.g.  I need to sum preceding rows only if the rating is within 1 of the current row.

Example data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
             (
                 Team varchar(1),
                 date date, 
                 Rating int, 
                 Score int
             );

INSERT INTO @tbl (Team, Date, Rating, Score)
VALUES
('a', '2020/12/05', '20', '1'),
('a', '2020/12/04', '18', '8'),
('a', '2020/12/03', '21', '3'),
('a', '2020/12/02', '19', '4'),
('a', '2020/12/01', '19', '3');
```

Current code:

```
SELECT
    Rating, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Rating >= (Rating-1) AND  Rating <= (Rating+1) THEN SCORE END) 
        OVER (partition by Team ORDER BY Date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS SUM
FROM
    @tbl
ORDER BY 
    Date DESC
```

Output:

```
    +------------------+------------+------------+
    |  Rating          | Current    | Required   | 
    +------------------+------------+------------+
    | 20               | 18         |     7      |
    | 18               | 10         |     7      |
    | 21               | 7          |     NULL   |
    | 19               | 3          |     3      |
    | 18               | NULL       |     NULL   |
    +------------------+------------+------------+
```

The problem is this following section of the code is not working as the rating is being assessed on a line by line by line basis.

```
CASE WHEN Rating >= (Rating-1) AND  Rating <= (Rating+1)
```

I need it to assess against the rating of the original row (I've looked into `Top` but that isn't working):

```
CASE WHEN Rating >= ((SELECT TOP 1 Rating) - 1) AND Rating <= ((SELECT TOP 1 Rating) + 1)
```

Any help appreciated as always.

Comment: What is your expectation from using `rating` vs `Rating`?

Comment: Apologies.  Should be all Rating.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **completely unsupported** (out of even extended support) by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Incorrect version was posted. Updated post to 2017.  Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like a lateral join:

```
SELECT t.*, t2.*
FROM @tbl t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(t2.score) as score_5
      FROM (SELECT TOP (5) t2.*
            FROM @tbl t2
            WHERE t2.date < t.date
            ORDER BY t2.date DESC
           ) t2
      WHERE t2.rating BETWEEN t.rating - 1 AND t.rating + 1
     ) t2
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  I tried the code with the sample data but I'm getting errors.  I'll play around with the lateral join idea.

Comment: Got it working with small changes (awaiting changes to be approved and I will accept).  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sql server syntax, but here's how to do it using Spark SQL. Essentially the idea is to create a row for each pair of rows which are within 5 rows of each other, and then do the `sum if`.

```
select
    Team, date, Rating,
    sum(case when old_score[0] between rating-1 and rating+1 then old_score[1] end) as sum
from (
    select
        *,
        explode_outer(scores) as old_score
    from (
        select
            *,
            collect_list(array(rating, score))
            over (partition by Team order by date rows between 5 preceding and 1 preceding) scores
        from tbl
    )
)
group by Team, date, Rating
order by Team, date, Rating;
```

which gives

```
a       2020-12-01      19      NULL
a       2020-12-02      19      3
a       2020-12-03      21      NULL
a       2020-12-04      18      7
a       2020-12-05      20      10
```

and reveals that you've probably made a mistake in your expected output ;)

Comment: Thank you for sharing and the ideas.  I'll play around and try to recreate.